# Yii2: Customize LinkPager to show Ellipses in pagination

Tags: css, pagination, yii2

I'm trying to get pagination as in the screenshot below.What settings can achieve such a pagination

[image: Pagination]

I am initializing the LinkPager like below

```
<?php echo LinkPager::widget([
            'pagination' => $pages,
            'prevPageLabel' => false,
            'nextPageLabel' => false,
            'maxButtonCount'=>2,
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'ip-mosaic__pagin-list',
            ],
        ]); ?>
```

Below the the HTML version of the pagination

```
<ul class="ip-mosaic__pagin-list">
            <li class="active-page"><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li class="ip-mosaic__pagin-dots"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i> <i class="fas fa-circle"></i> <i
                        class="fas fa-circle"></i></li>
            <li><a href="#">35</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: what is the output of the above-applied settings can you show the image or add the generated HTML for the pagination, just like you have added the template `HTML` add the resulting Html too. what are you not able to achieve with the above settings

Comment: added an answer see if that helps you out.

Comment: thanks you! think that's fine

Comment: Yes I have tested it on my local machine and it works fine you just need to provide your CSS classes along with the CSS file loaded and it will work. if you still run into any problems just come back and post here we will sort it out, the extension works similar to the default Yii's `LinkPager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your pagination image it seems like you are having trouble with the `Ellipses` that are inside the pagination as your implementation is correct just missing the `active-page` class, so if this is correct you should use the [**`Separated Pager for Yii2`**](https://github.com/justinvoelker/yii2-separatedpager) extension which extends the Yii2 LinkPager and adds the Ellipses.

[image]

A Yii2 `LinkPager` that displays the first and last pages inline with other pages.Rather than having dedicated "First" and "Last" buttons in your LinkPager, Separated Pager will show a standard set of page links but will also always include the first and last pages as the first and last page links. No more dedicated first/last buttons and no more guessing how many pages there are.

### Install the extension using

Either run

```
php composer.phar require --prefer-dist justinvoelker/yii2-separatedpager "*"
```

or add

```
"justinvoelker/yii2-separatedpager": "*"
```

### Your code should look like this

```
echo \justinvoelker\separatedpager\LinkPager::widget ( [
    'id'=>'my-pager',
    'pagination' => $pages ,
    'activePageCssClass' => 'active-page' ,
    'prevPageLabel' => false ,
    'nextPageLabel' => false ,
    'maxButtonCount' => 5 ,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'ip-mosaic__pagin-list'
    ]
] );
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I will try